# How to retrieve mulitple child nodes from firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data relating to a specific user in the database returned to a users screen in android studio. The data in firebase takes a format like so :

```
"studentNumber" : {
        "1234567" : {
            "CS320" :{
                "Lab 1" : "80%",
                "Lab 2" : "90%"
            },
            "CS255" :{
                "Lab 1" :"30%"
            }
        },
        "6234567" : {
            "CS320" :{
                "Lab 1" : "70%",
                "Lab 2" : "100%"
            },
```

and so on like that.

I am trying to get all data/child nodes ie all modules, subsequent labs and subsequent grades relating to one singular student returned to their screen in android studio, however, so far I have only been able to get the data returning to the console in android studio instead of the application screen.

This is the code I'm using to get the data.

```
  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("0000");
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.v("E_Value","Data :" +dataSnapshot.getValue());
           }
   }
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data for all students? In which case I would suggest using recyclerview. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Hi Ngugi, I'm trying to fetch data just for one user so, for example, all data relating to '1234567' above. Would a recyclerview work for that? I'm not familiar with it but could look into it.

Comment: What is the exact data that you want to get? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i'm looking to get all of this returned "1234567" : {
            "CS320" :{
                "Lab 1" : "80%",
                "Lab 2" : "90%"
            },
            "CS255" :{
                "Lab 1" :"30%"
            }

Comment: What do you mean through "get all of this"?

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry this is my first time developing in android studio so forgive my terminology. I wish to retrieve the data I just mentioned and display it to a users screen so that they can see all of their results and grades, hopefully, this clarifies things.

Comment: Is "studentNumber" your initial node? Are "Users" and "studentNumber" different nodes in the database?

Comment: @mayur users is the initial node and then each user will have unique student numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the code, however the outline should look like this.

You should be fetching one key and call a function to obtain the value and the subsequent nodes related to it and their values.

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("0000");
  databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String studentKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
             fetchDetails(studentKey);
        }
     }
   }

   public void fetchDetails(String studentKey) {
       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("0000").child(studentKey);
       ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String courseKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey(); //this should print CS320
             fetchDetailsOfCourse(courseKey);
        }
        }
     }
   }

   public void fetchDetailsOfCourse(String courseKey) {

      System.out.System.out.println("Course key: " + courseKey);
       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child("0000").child(studentKey).child(courseKey);
       ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String lab1 = dataSnapshot.child("lab1").getValue(String.class);
            String lab2 = dataSnapshot.child("lab2").getValue(String.class);

            System.out.println("Lab1 value: " + lab1); //this should get the values for lab1
            System.out.println("Lab2 value: " + lab2); //this should get the values for lab2

        }
        }
     }
   }
```